# Photodiode Output measurement

Tags: adc, photodiode, energy, radiation

I'm using ***Hamamatshu s8559 photodiode*** to convert x-rays into it's respective energy.

I'm using a 10 bit ADC converter.

> The problem I'm facing is I have no relationship between the Photo-current and respective X-Ray Energy.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

This is the circuit I'm using, leave the ADC part I'm measuring voltage across R2.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Probably a good idea to test it then. Start with low energy, measure the output, stick it in an excel spreadsheet. Turn the x-ray energy up bit by bit and copy down the output, eventually you'll gather enough data to perform some sort of calibration routine.

Comment: I don't have any known or constant source of x-ray. Is there any other way, mathematically?

Comment: When suitable (short wavelength) photons arrive, the sensor produces an output charge spike. How can you produce that effect in your hardware?

Comment: I'm using an medical X-Ray machine, which have input params like kVp, mA and mAs. So i Have no idea how much of radiation or energy is received at the sensor. I'm logging the ADC  values into a csv file, but those values are void until they are converted into energy or radiation.

Comment: See the link in MCG answer, the resistor is 100 times higher than yours. 10M to 100M ohm, so it is the output voltage.

Comment: At such high impedaance the circuit must be shielded. Also , I don't think that it's a good ideea to place an ADC so close without a buffer. ADC is a source of noise. Use a schematic from MCG link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Google, the S8559 is just a detection module. The photodiode that is inside is the [S1337](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s1337_series_kspd1032e.pdf) and looking at page 2 on the datasheet, you can see this graph:

[image]

You should be able to use this to gather information on how the diode responds.

Another page I found in Google is [HERE](http://www.fusor.eu/monitors.html#X-ray_Gamma_Counter). This has some nice explanations on how to use this detection module.

Comment: That was helpful, but can you me through calibrating this sensor? This is the first time I'm working on sensors. I would prefer calibrating it mathematically, I don't have any known source of x-ray.

Comment: I've never worked with it so no, I won't be able to help. You'll have to go through practical tests to gather data as I mentioned in my comment

Answer (score 1):

First off maybe you might want to use a more linear method of measurement like a Trans-Impedance Amplifier [(TIA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier).  This is a nifty and simple little circuit that will give you a usable and low noise voltage output that is linear in the amount of optical power that is on the sensor. This type of pre-amplifier circuit will at least remove some of the uncertainty from the detector by making the photodiode stage response a predictable linear one. It also makes the detector faster. The gain of the TIA amplifier is just the responsivity of the silicon photodiode (A/W) times the feedback resistor (ohms).  You just need to set the feedback resistor small enough that the ADC is not saturated when x-rays are at maximum.

Working out the incident X-ray power to great accuracy is tough. The whole Hamamatshu s8559 sensor is actually a regular silicon photodiode with an X-ray converter medium glued to the top. The data sheet gives you most of what you need for a first guess at the math only calibration: 52 nA for 120 kV, 1.0 mA at 830 mm with a 6 mm Al filter. You need to work out what the the expected x-ray flux using 1/r^2 rule and attenuation from the filter. But the power going into the calibration system would have been P=VxI, which should give you a rough first guess.  So you need to know what the actual efficiency of the conversion into x-rays is and the attenuation through 6 mm of aluminium.

Maybe you should post the model number of your X-ray source.  If you have volts and current numbers then to first order that tells you how much energy is going in.  That will put an upper bound on the amount of x-rays generated and you can work back from there based on the distance from emitter to detector and whatever filters you have in the way. From there you can just multiply by the photodetector responsivity and the Trans-Impedance Amplifier's feedback resistor value to get the final calibrated X-ray power.

Comment: This is the reason. You need a transimpedance amp to get a linear output from a photodiode. It's not a voltage source.